# Given $A\in\mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ and $AX=XB$, can I find $B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations, matrix-equations

Given $\textbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ and the form of Sylvester's equation, $\textbf{AX}=\textbf{XB}$, where $\textbf{X}\in\mathbb{C}^{2 \times 2}$ is unknown, is it possible to find $\textbf{B}$? The problem seems underdetermined, but the form of $\textbf{A}$ is so tempting,

$$\textbf{A}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ a & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$.

I guess what I'm wondering is whether it is possible to write down a post-multiplication given the explicit form of a pre-multiplication. Fiddling with the algebra seems to make me doubt it, but nothing I've done seems definitive, only obstructed.

Comment: Are we given that the equation has a unique solution (for $X$)?

Comment: If $X = 0$, then $B$ could be anything ...

Comment: Yes. We can assume that $X$ can be found uniquely.

Comment: @user153764 if that's all the information we have, then the most we can say is that $B$ has no eigenvalues in common with $A$.  In your case, $B$ should not have eigenvalues $\pm \sqrt{a}$ (assuming $a \geq 0$).

Comment: @user153764 actually, your phrasing "write down a post-multiplication given the explicit form of a pre-multiplication" makes it think that I misinterpreted.  It seems, from that last statement, that you're asking the following: given $A$, what is the matrix $B$ such that $AX = XB$ **for all matrices $X$**.  Was *this* your question all along?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes. That's the question. Knowledge of the matrix $X$ would have to come from a solution to a matrix differential equation that would need knowledge of $B$.